# Calculating eigenvalues for $N \times N$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question where I am asked suppose we have an $(N \times N)$ matrix with one's on the diagonal, and constant, $c$ everywhere else. What would you expect the eigenvalues to be ?

I tried calculating it using a $(2\times 2)$ matrix, but I then got stuck for $(3\times 3)$ and so forth. Is there some sort of trick that can be used here ?

Comment: The matrix of all ones can be written as $e e^T$ where $e$ is a vector of ones and it is straightforward to compute the eigenvalues. Multiply by $c$ and add an appropriate multiply of $I$ to get the matrix above. What would that do to the eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Let $A$ be this matrix. Then 
$$A-(1-c)I$$
is the matrix with $c$ in all entries. This matrix has rank 1.

Therefore $(1-c)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ of geometric multiplicity $N-1$. It follows that $1-c$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ of algebraic multiplicity at least $N-1$.

Therefore, $N-1$ eigenvalue are equal to $1-c$. Use the fact that $\tr(A)$ is the sum of all eigenvalues to find the last eigenvalue.

Comment: wait sorry, because $A - (1-c)I$ is a rank 1 matrix, how were you able to conclude that $(1-c)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $N-1$ ? Would you be able to refer me to this theorem or help explain why ?

Comment: @PutsandCalls: What dimension would the kernel of a rank one operator be?

Comment: @PutsandCalls The rank nullity theorem says that the dimension of the eigenspace plus the rank of $(A-\lambda I)$ equals $N$.

Answer (score 0):

It is  well known that all one matrix ($n\times n$) given as $J$ has $n-1$ zero eigenvalues and $n$ as single positive eigenvalue. Multiplying by a scalar $cJ$ has $n-1$ zeros and eigenvalue $cn$  Adding: $cJ+(1-c)I$ you add to each eigenvalue of $cJ$, $1-c$ to get all of them.